# How do I use a preprocess function for a custom template?

Tags: 8, theming

The content of this page is taken from a template file called
hello-world.html.twig

In my module file I have created the following
hello.module file

```
function hello_theme() {
  return array(
    'hello_world' => array(
    'variables' => array('account' => NULL),
    'template' => 'hello-world',
  ),
}

function template_preprocess_hello_world(&$variables) {
  $variables['test'] = $variables['account'];
}
```

In my controller file I have called the theme as following

```
function hello_world_browse() {
  $output = array(
    '#theme'=>'hello_world',
    '#account'=>'testing',
  );
  return $output;
}
```

When I try to print `{{ test }}` in hello-world.tpl.php twig file it is not printing.

Comment: "The content of this page is taken from a template file called hello-world.tpl.php" - Surely you mean hello-world.html.twig? Does everything else in your template display correctly?

Comment: Please post your solution, so it may be helpful to others who have the same problem.